# GDB convenince variables

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I have function like this

```
int xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_For_xxx(int val1, int val2, int val3, short int *FillVal)
```

This FillVal is supposed to put the result on processing val1, val2 and val3.
So, I attached this process on GDB, and I did this.

```
set $myvar=(int*)malloc(4)
call xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_For_xxx(1, 40, 0, $myvar)
```

On call, the return value is correct. So, the function call ended successfully.
Now, if I print the value of $myVar in gdb by this.

```
print *$myvar
```

I get garbage value. but, in the log dump I could see that proper value was put 
inside *FillVal.

Why is this happening? I tried some sample program on cygwin(intel), which works fine.
but, when I try this on powerPC(linux). The above mentioned problem occurs.

Comment: Does the result change when compiler optimizations are disabled? Can you try `x/wx $myvar` or `x/gx $myvar` and see whether the same garbage value is given? Is the garbage value or part of it the big-endian swap of the true value?

Comment: Do you need to typecast when printing, to force a particular interpretation of `$myvar`?  ie.  `*(int *)$myvar`?

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments. But, it is my mistake, as I had mistakenly marked FillVal as int*, it is actually short int*. I changed allocation from 4 bytes to 2 bytes. It works fine now :)